# recursive globbing **/* and */**

Tags: bash, wildcards

I am learning the wildcards recursive globbing and tried

```
$ ls **/* | wc -l
15
$ ls */** | wc -l
15
```

They output identical results.

Is there any distinction between `**/*` and `*/**`?

Answer (score 7):

`*/**` will only match directories (and their subdirectories & files); it will not match files (non-directories) in the current directory, because the `*/` portion of it requires a directory prefix before beginning the `**` globstar expansion.  As for `**/*`, the trailing `/*` is extraneous, since the `**` will, by itself, expand to every file and directory under the current directory (subject to the `dotglob` option). Since every directory has been expanded by that point, the trailing `/*` does not match anything.

Be careful using `ls` to test, since it will "helpfully" read *into* any directories that you might pass it; consider instead something like:

```
printf "%s\n" */**
printf "%s\n" **/*
```

Also note that piping to `wc -l` could mislead you for actual counts; consider:

```
$ touch a $'b\nc'
$ ls -1
a
b?c
$ ls | wc -l
3     ## WRONG!
```

Comment: Also beware that in `zsh` (the original implementation of recursive globbing), `**` alone is not special (it's the same as `*`), only `**/` is (short for `(*/)#`). The API is different again in `fish`. See [The result of ls \* , ls \*\* and ls \*\*\*](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/62665) for details.

Comment: The `ls **/* | wc -l` issues can be worked around by using `ls -qd -- **/* | wc -l`